# osCommerce, ZenCart & CubeCart - Which is easier to customize?

Tags: e-commerce, oscommerce, zen-cart

Which one of OsCommerce, ZenCar and CubeCart is the easiest to customize with a custom design template? I know ZenCart is an offshoot of osCommerce so I'd guess they would be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZenCart and OSC are similar, but I would recommend Zencart over a standard OSC for template customization. I haven't used CubeCart.

If your modifications are only html/css customizations for one shop you should be fine with Zencart, although there are quite a lot of files to make a full template, with the modification of a few files on an already made template you will go a long way.

With the default template, I would suggest starting with:

- Under the common folder: html_header.php, tpl_header.php, tpl_tabular_display.php, tpl_columnar_display.php, tpl_main_page.php and tpl_footer.php.
- Sideboxes folder: the sideboxes you plan to use if you require html changes to them, perhaps you won't, with CSS you should be able to modify their appearance quite a lot.
- Under the Templates folder: you will probably need to modify the html in the checkout pages, the product_info_display page and the half a dozen listing pages.

You don't mention [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/en/allfeatures). It is a much more modern software than Zencart or OSC (code wise), completely written with OOP and, more importantly, it uses [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) for its easy to follow template system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. It was only restricted to those as they were the ones given to me by the client..... however it appears they are now open to other carts as well. :) But yes I agree that PrestaShop is nice :)

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but just wanted to add that CubeCart uses the Smarty template system as well.